# Is there a better map structure?

Tags: dictionary, ftp, structure

Not sure whether I'm allowed to ask this question on here, but ima go ahead and see what happens! :-)

My question is as following; whats the best map structure for a website? Like, where do you place your pages and so on? I usually use this structure:

css/

images/

js/

includes/

pages/

Any tips on how to improve my map structure and why?

Comment: What is a "map structure"?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

resources/css
resources/js
resources/includes
resources/images

webapp/pages
webapp/ajax

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal structure you are using and is completely ok. As a web support tech I could move around that structure with out any questions asked.

WEBSITE.COM in this directory you should have ->Index.html - contactus.html - aboutus.html and so on with all of the relative folders such as contact us folder about us and so on with files needed for that page in each folder/directory.

You can continue with your structure. All is fine!